# Spring - Cannot find class file for org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

i do some research about this problem, but i could'nt find a proper solution. Im quite new in this topic, and everything went well till i try use hibernate.

Heres my stacktrace:

```
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:43 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule 

begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:blog' did not find a matching property.
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.75
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jan 18 2017 20:54:42 UTC
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.75.0
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_111-b14
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\A1.1SPRING\NowyProjekt\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\A1.1SPRING\NowyProjekt\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\A1.1SPRING\NowyProjekt\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\endorsed
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1250
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_111/lib/amd64;C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;D:\Python344\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin;C:\Users\Karol\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Users\Karol\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;D:\Node\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;D:\DEV\tool\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;D:\DEV\tool\apache-maven-3.3.9;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Users\Karol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Users\Karol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\;C:\Users\Karol\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\AASPRING\sts-bundle\sts-3.8.3.RELEASE;;.
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1099 ms
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.75
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:44 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [126] milliseconds.
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:44 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\A1.1SPRING\NowyProjekt\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\blog\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.4.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 3.0, section 10.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5634)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3205)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1373)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1861)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.registerTransactionalEventListenerFactory(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:92)
    at org.springframework.transaction.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java:60)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1424)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.event.EventListenerFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1892)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1735)
    ... 39 more

kwi 06, 2017 5:35:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/blog] startup failed due to previous errors
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:171)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:5165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5829)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1571)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1561)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

kwi 06, 2017 5:35:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
kwi 06, 2017 5:35:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4665 ms
```

and my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
    <display-name>blog</display-name>



    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
      /WEB-INF/spring/webcontext/DispatcherServlet-context.xml
   </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Applicationcontext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.3.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.web.blog">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
            expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="HSQL" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        id="emf">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.web.blog.entity"></property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        id="TransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>blog</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
</project>
```

[thats my project file-tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhICE.png)

i will be gratefulfor your help!

Comment: i forgot to writte, before i added <tx:annotation-driven/> there wanst error, after in applicationContex.xml i got : Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for org/springframework/context/event/EventListenerFactory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is version mismatch issue with dependecny of spring-context. try with different version of spring-context.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```